# how to create element contains information from the form i created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really a beginner but i like challenges, i need to create a Div block contains HTML code that contains information from the form i created by submitting a button, for example, the information is the name, picture, and text. the code i did down creating a div block contains just the information from the form.
my html

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addNew);

});

const addNew = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  addname = document.getElementById('name').value;
  addDiv = document.querySelector('div-cont');

  newDiv.classList.add('div-color');
  newDiv.innerHTML = addname; /* i want HTML code here so i can style it, something like this '<h6 class="text-capitalize "><span class="name">name :</span><span id="user-name">the name from the form here</span></h6>'*/
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

};
```

```html
<h1>make new divs</h1>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Send</button>
</form>

<div id="div-cont">
  <h2>the container</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the issue here?

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/f6ayug7m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) backticks, which allow use multiline text and insert variables:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addNew);

});

const addNew = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  addname = document.getElementById('name').value;
  addDiv = document.querySelector('div-cont');

  newDiv.classList.add('div-color');
  newDiv.innerHTML = `<h6 class="text-capitalize">
    <span class="name">name :</span>
    <span id="user-name">${addname}</span>
  </h6>`;
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

};
```

```css
.text-capitalize
{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: red;
}

.name
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>make new divs</h1>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Send</button>
</form>

<div id="div-cont">
  <h2>the container</h2>
</div>
```

A better approach would be create a "template" within your html file and use it instead, this will allow easier management, use complex structure and fast and easy move/copy it around the page where/when needed:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addNew);

});
const templates = document.getElementById("templates");
const addNew = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const tags = (a, b) => 
  {
    if (b in tags.list)
      return tags.list[b];

    const r = b.split('.').reduce((v, k) => (v || {})[k], tags.list);
    return r === undefined ? a : r;
  }

  tags.regex = /\${([^}]+)}/g;
  tags.list = { //collection of variables data to replace in html with
    addname: document.getElementById('name').value,
    count: 1,
    whateverName: "blah",
    complex: {
      object: {
        no_problem: "yes"
      }
    }
  }
  const newDiv = templates.querySelector(".div-color").cloneNode(true);
  newDiv.innerHTML = newDiv.innerHTML.replace(tags.regex, tags);
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

  const template2 = templates.querySelector(".template2");
  for(let i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
    const templ = template2.cloneNode(true);
    templ.innerHTML = templ.innerHTML.replace(tags.regex, tags);
    document.body.appendChild(templ);
    tags.list.count++;
  }
};
```

```css
.text-capitalize
{
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: red;
}

.name
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* hide templates */
#templates
{
  display: none;
}

.template2
{
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>make new divs</h1>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Send</button>
</form>

<div id="div-cont">
  <h2>the container</h2>
</div>

<div id="templates">
  <div class="div-color">
    <h6 class="text-capitalize">
      <span class="name">name :</span>
      <span id="user-name">${addname}</span>
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="template2">
    <h1 class="text-capitalize">
      <span>${whateverName}:</span>
      <span class="count">${count}</span>
      <h3>none-existing tags ignored: ${nonExistingTag}</h3>
      <h3>even complex objects supported: ${complex.object.no_problem}</h3>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u so much i will study it first so i can understand what i am putting in my code